# How can I add feature information from one json into geoJson using id/codarea as the identifier?

Tags: json, python-3.x, leaflet, geojson

The following steps show where you can download the files to reproduce this question. How can I add municipality information from one json object into the other using id/codarea as the identifier.

## Requesting geojson

```
import folium
import os
import requests

url = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/malhas/?resolucao=5&formato=application/vnd.geo+json&qualidade=4'
    
    meshes_mun = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

File structure snippet:

```
   {'type': 'Feature',
       'properties': {'codarea': '2303600',
        'centroide': [-36.722055140733, -6.158308569735204]},
       'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[[-36.6532, -6.1118],
          [-36.6828, -6.1277],
          [-36.7005, -6.1453],
.....
```

In the following you can find string names and ids that I want to link with the `meshes_mun` above.
The names and ids I need to link with is the higher level: `'id': 2303600, 'nome': 'Catarina'`, so don't need to add the other features, but they could be added if it's ok.

```
# url to request information of all municipalities (contains the id number)
mun_url = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/municipios'

cities_json = requests.get(mun_url, headers=headers).json()
```

File structure snippet:

```
{'id': 2303600,
  'nome': 'Catarina',
  'microrregiao': {'id': 23020,
   'nome': 'Sertão de Inhamuns',
   'mesorregiao': {'id': 2304,
    'nome': 'Sertões Cearenses',
    'UF': {'id': 23,
     'sigla': 'CE',
     'nome': 'Ceará',
     'regiao': {'id': 2, 'sigla': 'NE', 'nome': 'Nordeste'}}}}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I add feature information from one json into geoJson using id/codarea as the identifier?

Can be done something like this

```
import requests

url = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/malhas/?resolucao=5&formato=application/vnd.geo+json&qualidade=4"
meshes_mun = requests.get(url).json()

mun_url = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/municipios"
cities_json = requests.get(mun_url).json()

for mun in meshes_mun["features"]:
    codarea = int(mun["properties"]["codarea"])
    matched_city = [city for city in cities_json if city["id"] == codarea][0]
    mun["properties"]["nome"] = matched_city["nome"]
```